# How to Add Header to ODataClient (Apache Olingo)?

Tags: java, olingo

I am having a trouble accessing the odata service, because it requires a specific header, and I couldn't add it directly on the ODataClient, does anyone have any idea on how to solve my problem?

Psuedo Code:

```
ODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getClient(); 
client.addHeader("Header","123456789"); // <---- this code is what I am seeking
URI customersUri = client.newURIBuilder("uri/northwindmodel.svc")
          .appendEntitySetSegment("Customers").build();
ODataRetrieveResponse<ODataEntitySetIterator<ODataEntitySet, ODataEntity>> response
 = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getEntitySetIteratorRequest(customersUri).execute();
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
    <artifactId>odata-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ODataClient` does not have and API to set additional headers, probably because it directly doesn't own `HttpClient` directly. Its owned my `AbstractODataRequest`class, so you have APIs to set additonal headers per HTTP request.

In your case you can use `addCustomHeader` method in `ODataRequest`.

Ex. Your sample code can be refactored in the following way to achieve the goal.

```
ODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getClient(); 
// client.addHeader("Header","123456789"); // <---- this code is what I am seeking
URI customersUri = client.newURIBuilder("uri/northwindmodel.svc")
        .appendEntitySetSegment("Customers").build();

ODataEntitySetIteratorRequest<ClientEntitySet, ClientEntity> entitySetIteratorRequest =
        client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getEntitySetIteratorRequest(qryUri);

entitySetIteratorRequest.addCustomHeader("Custom-Header-key", "Custom-Header-Value");

ODataRetrieveResponse<ClientEntitySetIterator<ClientEntitySet, ClientEntity>> response = entitySetIteratorRequest.execute();
```